# laravel components not working on live server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm new to vue.js, its my first experience for using Laravel and vue.js together.
Right now I have a problem for rendering vue.js externally.
It works in "localhost:8000" but it doesn't work in 192.168.100.34.
Additionally, I have already executed all cache clearing methods on Laravel, but I have the same issue.

Comment: Could you please share how you have done in your code?

Comment: Are you compiling the vue code?

Comment: Hello @Polaris , What do you mean?

Comment: Are you running npm run watch or 'npm run production' if on production server?

Comment: yes, i am! It works fine in "localhost:8000" when used in a virtual machine, but it doesn't work in 192.168.100.34.